# D3 bar graph not showing up

Tags: d3.js

I am making a bar chart in d3 but when I run locally and on Git it only shows the axes and not the bars.

Code and data: https://github.com/pshukl21/narrativevis.git

Answer (score 2):

This can be frustrating! Looks like there are a couple of things going on, but the main thing is that your data had an extra line that was causing `d3.csv` to read it in improperly.

[**Here's the original, unmodified version of your code in a Codesandbox, only with that space deleted.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-gagarin-ucxop?file=/index.html)

Delete the space and you can continue building your chart.

[image]

**Solution:**

A good thing to do when reading data into d3 is to do a quick sanity check by using the browser's developer console.

Using the dev tools to inspect, we can see that it looks like we're not getting a value that our D3 code expects -- it's telling us that the function that renders the `rect` is seeing `NaN`, which is a clue for where we can look.

[image: inspecting d3 with the browser's developer tools]

And on closer inspection of the array that `d3.csv` creates, there's something off -- an extra row with no data. That appears to throw our entire array off!

[image: missing values in csv array]

Sure enough, turns out that Github was trying to warn us about this, too, but the soft colored, quiet warning is pretty easy to miss.

[image: Github warning message about missing csv values]

Once that's fixed, there may another problem -- we'll need to convert the values in `career_WS` to a number, or else our chart won't render and we'll get this helpful warning in the console:

[image]

We can do that by looping through our data and using the "+", which is a common replacement for `parseFloat` when working with D3.

```
data.forEach((row) => {
  row.career_WS = +row.career_WS;
});
```

After we clean our data and make sure it's being read in, things are coming together.

It looks like there's still some work to do.

[image: d3 chart rendering after data read in]

Fortunately, that is all in the implementation details -- it's not what your question was asking, but from here it's a matter of setting margins, setting scales, and rendering our chart.

Again, using the developer tools is a great way to understand what's failing. Hope this was helpful! ✌️